# MacOS application screen size

Tags: xcode, macos

How to setup screen size in Xcode for MacOS application? Do I need to do it programmatically?
I didn't find any settings in Interface Builder related to it or manuals.
Thanks!

Comment: See `NSScreen`, you can't change the size of a screen. Do you mean window size? Select the window in IB and drag a corner or use the size inspector.

Comment: Yes, window size. I have iOS-MacOS app and there is no Size Inspector in IB.